$\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$-Stabilizer size of a representation of a finitely generated group
Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a field of $q$ elements where $q$ is an odd prime power. Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $\rho:G \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$ be an irreducible representation over $F_q$ which is not absolutely irreducible. Let $\operatorname{Frob}_q$ be the Frobenius map sending $x\in \overline{F}_q$ to $x^q\in \overline{F}_q$.
By my other question, $\rho$ of the form $V\oplus \operatorname{Frob}_q(V)$, where $V$ is a 1-dimensional representation of $G$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$

What is the size of the stabilizer of $V\oplus \operatorname{Frob}_q(V)$ by the $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$-action by conjugation?

I thought it was easier to find the stabilizers in $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$ then identify scalar matrices. Taking any matrix $A\in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$, and identifying $A\cdot \rho(G) = \rho(G)\cdot A$, we can see that $A$ should be a diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(a,\operatorname{Frob}_q(a))$ with $a\in \mathbb F_{q^2}^{\times}$. I am tempted to say that $|Stab_{\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_q)}(\rho)| = q+1$, through experimenting with small fields (e.g. for $\mathbb F_3$ with Frobenius $x\to x^3$, I found that the stabilizer is of size 4).
Is there any way to confirm or infirm this for any $q$?
Thanks for your help.

It seems to me that the matrices $\rho(g), g\in G$, span (over $\Bbb{F}q$) a copy $L$ of $\Bbb{F}{q^2}$ inside $R=M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{F}_2)$. Then $L$ is self-centralizing in $R$. Consequently $L$ is also the centralizer of $\rho(G)$, implying that your hunch is correct. I can't spend more time on this now. It's getting late, and tomorrow will be a rough day.

Many thanks! I will think more about your hint.

Double centralizer is overkill. $\Bbb{F}_q^2$ is a 1-dimensional vector space over $L$, so anything commuting with multiplication by elements of $L$ is necessarily one of those!

I couldn't see how to use your hint. If $L=\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ is the centralizer of $\rho(G)$, how do we see that the size of ths stabilizer is $q+1$?

Is the stabilizer in the projective linear group gotten by moding out the scalars? So $L^/\Bbb{F}_q^$, which is a cyclic group of order $q+1$.

Many thanks! I think I am just confused by the fact that the stabilizer should contain elements of $\operatorname{PGL}2(F_q)$ while $L$ is over $F{q^2}$. So maybe here we are looking at the stabilizer inside  $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\overline{\mathbb F}_q)$, and not $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_q)$?
